# For loop with inline parameter list

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am executing the same long parametrized command on about a dozen different values, but let's take this short and simple example:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "Test-A1"
ECHO "Test-A2"
ECHO "Test-B1"
```

I now want to make this more maintainable, deduplicating the command using a loop:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %A IN ("A1 A2 B1") DO ECHO "Test-%A"
```

The expected output would be the same as in the first example, but the actual output is only the first line (`Test-A1`).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do not use `/F` the option: `for %%A in (A1 A2 B1) do echo Test-%%A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different types and behaviors of FOR loops.

You need to study the documentation and make sure you are using the correct one.

Your use of FOR /F will parse a single string into 1 or more tokens, with a single iteration.

You want to use the simple FOR, and you need to drop the quotes so that you get multiple iterations. A quoted string will count as one iteration.

Also, you must double the percents when you use the FOR command in a batch file.

```
for %%A IN (A1 A2 B1) DO ECHO "Test-%%A"
```